# Default value in react-ranger with redux form

Tags: reactjs, slider, redux-form

i'm using react-slider which i made compatible with redux form and i want it to have default Values which i pass.
My component looks like this:

```
export default field => (
  <div>
    <Range
      onChange={field.input.onChange}
      value1={field.input.value1 ? field.input.value1 : field.min}
      value2={field.input.value2 ? field.input.value1 : field.max}
      // min={0}
      // max={162}
      defaultValue={[field.min, field.max]}
    >
      {field.children}
    </Range>
    {field.meta.touched && field.meta.error &&
    <span className="error">{field.meta.error}</span>}
  </div>
);
```

and i render it here:

```
<Field
                            id="value-slider"
                            name="value-slider"
                            component={MyRange}
                            min={minPrice}
                            max={maxPrice}
                          />
```

But it does not seem to work. Any ideas what i'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:
I've edited my Range component like this:

```
export default field => (
  <div>
    <Range
      {...field}
      onChange={field.input.onChange}
      value1={field.input.value1}
      value2={field.input.value2}
      // min={0}
      // max={162}
      // defaultValue={[0, 162]}
    >
      {field.children}
    </Range>
    {field.meta.touched && field.meta.error &&
    <span className="error">{field.meta.error}</span>}
  </div>
);
```

and then i've add

```
min={minPrice}
                            max={maxPrice}
                            defaultValue={[minPrice, maxPrice]}
```